# Prevent modal popup from opening on enter click (PC) or Start click (Mobile device)

Tags: jquery

I have found a strange issue in a page of my website and have no clue how to prevent it from happening.
On short, i have several input fields, radio buttons, input area and a popup modal that is triggered when i click on a button. All is fine until i click on any input type="text" and if i click on Enter key (PC) or on Start button from the keyboard (Mobile device) (like you insert a text or a number and than you press enter on keyboard to move forward). When i click like that, the popup modal opens.

So, is there any way i can prevent this?

The jquery which launches the popup is like this

```
  $('.change-button, .see-categories').click(function(){
    $('body').addClass('noscroll');
    $('.add-item-categories-wrap').show();
    $('.selected-category').hide();
    $('.fa-chevron-circle-left').hide();
 });
```

Comment: Is the website live? i.e. is there somewhere we can have a look at the rest of the code too? Maybe a jsfiddle if not?

Comment: Website is in development and is passworded.  How can i provide details on private?

Comment: Don't provide me any details in private, don't be too trusting. Include all other relevant parts of your code (both js and html) in your question.

Comment: No, i am not trusting. I would provide just the data so you can see the website not to change the actual files. It is difficult to post the code since many fields come from php files like <?php ItemForm::price_input_text(); ?> .I provide usually all the necessary codes but in this case will not be possible.